# Docker Environment Variable

Tags: variables, docker, environment

I am using Hyperledger Fabric docker image and want to set docker-compose and docker environment variables inside the docker container. I tried setting the environment variables in docker-compose.yaml but still i am not able to access the environment variables insider docker container. I need these to be set so that when I make changes in the docker container then I can commit those changes. Else every time I have to set the environment variables.

Please let me know how this can be done.

My environment details:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   4845c56
 Built:        Mon Apr  3 18:07:42 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   4845c56
 Built:        Mon Apr  3 18:07:42 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

Operating System - Ubuntu 16.04
```

Comment: you cloud use and entrypoint script that sets these variables

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file